# Python pandas complex group by

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a Pandas data frame (df) with 3 columns:
"Drug" , "Affect" , "Journal"
Every row is a scientific paper and each paper states what effect the drug has on the disease. Example:

> ```
>        Drug      Affect    Journal
>        aspirin  downregulate  paper1
>        aspririn downregulate  paper2
>        aspirin  upregulate    paper3
>        aspirin  neutral       paper4
>        aspirin  downregulate  paper5
>        aspririn upregulate    paper6
>        iboruprofen  upregulate   paper7
>        iboruprofen  upregulate   paper8
>        iboruprofen  downregulate paper9
>        other_drug     ...            ...
> ```

The output should look like this:

> Drug
> aspirin

I want to make a filter of the df to get only the drugs that in the majority of the papers show to downregulate the disease, so if aspirin for example has 3 papers that tell that it downregulates and 2 papers that say that it upregulates and 1 that says that it has a neutral effect then we assume that the majority of the evidence show that the effect is to downregulate. So I want to have aspirin in my filtered df. Therefore, iboruprofen should not make it to my filtered df.

How do I make the group by? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by drug and the affect to count the number of records.

```
df_grouped = df.groupby(["Drug","Affect"], as_index=False).count()
```

The output:

```
    Drug         Affect        Journal
0   aspirin      downregulate    3
1   aspirin      neutral         1 
2   aspirin      upregulate      2
3   iboruprofen  downregulate    1
4   iboruprofen  upregulate      2
```

Loop over the unique drug list and check the numbers. If downregulate > upregulate, add this drug to result list.

```
result_drugs = []
for drug in np.unique(df["Drug"]:
    numberOfdownregulate = df_grouped[(df_grouped["Drug"] == drug) & (df_grouped["Affect"] == "downregulate")].Journal.values[0]
    numberOfupregulate = df_grouped[(df_grouped["Drug"] == drug) & (df_grouped["Affect"] == "upregulate")].Journal.values[0]
    result = numberOfdownregulate - numberOfupregulate
    
    if result > 0:
        result_drugs.append(drug)
```

Finally, filter your original dataframe.

```
df[df["Drug"].isin(result_drugs)]
```

If you only want to have dataframe with the desired drug values.

```
pd.DataFrame(result_drugs, columns=["Drug"])
```

Final output:

```
    Drug
0   aspirin
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative option would be using `convtools` library:

```py
from convtools import conversion as c

# fmt: off
input_data = [
    {'Drug': 'aspirin', 'Affect': 'downregulate', 'Journal': 'paper1'},
    {'Drug': 'aspririn', 'Affect': 'downregulate', 'Journal': 'paper2'},
    {'Drug': 'aspirin', 'Affect': 'upregulate', 'Journal': 'paper3'},
    {'Drug': 'aspirin', 'Affect': 'neutral', 'Journal': 'paper4'},
    {'Drug': 'aspirin', 'Affect': 'downregulate', 'Journal': 'paper5'},
    {'Drug': 'aspririn', 'Affect': 'upregulate', 'Journal': 'paper6'},
    {'Drug': 'iboruprofen', 'Affect': 'upregulate', 'Journal': 'paper7'},
    {'Drug': 'iboruprofen', 'Affect': 'upregulate', 'Journal': 'paper8'},
    {'Drug': 'iboruprofen', 'Affect': 'downregulate', 'Journal': 'paper9'}
]
# fmt: on

converter = (
    c.group_by(c.item("Drug"))
    .aggregate(
        {
            "drug": c.item("Drug"),
            "down": c.ReduceFuncs.Count(
                where=c.item("Affect") == "downregulate"
            ),
            "up": c.ReduceFuncs.Count(where=c.item("Affect") == "upregulate"),
            "neutral": c.ReduceFuncs.Count(
                where=c.item("Affect") == "neutral"
            ),
        }
    )
    .filter(
        c.and_(
            c.item("down") > c.item("up"),
            c.item("down") > c.item("neutral"),
        )
    )
    # after the above the result is:
    #   [{"drug": "aspirin", "down": 2, "up": 1, "neutral": 1}]
    .iter(c.item("drug"))
    .as_type(list)
    .gen_converter()
)

assert converter(input_data) == ["aspirin"]
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler approach using [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html) and [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html):

```
(
    df.groupby("Drug")
    .filter(lambda x: x["Affect"].value_counts().nlargest(1).index[0] == "downregulate")
    .get(["Drug"])
    .drop_duplicates()
)
```

`values_counts` returns counts for every unique value in `Affect` column.
`nlargest(1)` returns single row with the highest count
`index` returns an array with the name of the most frequent item